# How do I remove null items from a nested list in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I'm looking for the most efficient and/or most readable way to remove null items from a nested list structure in Dart. The list to filter is from a network response and we must assume one of the inner lists or any of the inner list items can be null. The method signature would look like this:

```
Iterable<Iterable<int>> removeNullItems(Iterable<Iterable<int?>?> nullableItemList) {

}
```

For a flat list I would usually use `whereType<int>()`, but this doesn't work for nested structures like `whereType<Iterable<int>>()`.

Answer (score 0):

The neatest way I found to do this:

```
Iterable<Iterable> removeNullItems(
    Iterable<Iterable<int?>?> nullableItemList) {
  return nullableItemList
      .whereType<Iterable>()
      .map((e) => e.whereType<int>());
}
```

Comment: That's what I'd do too. Perhaps use [`whereNotNull`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableNullableExtension/whereNotNull.html) from `package:collection`